# store command output to array in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm using ssh to connect to a remote machine and read a log file there. From that log file, based on some tokens, I extract specific logs and store it in a variable. Every log is in new line in the log file and the data can contain any character including white space.

```
array=("$(egrep "UserComments/propagateBundle-2013-10-19--04:42:13|UserComments/propagateBundle-2013-10-19--04:38:36|UserComments/propagateBundle-2013-10-19--04:34:24" <path>/propagateBundle.log)")
echo ${array[0]}
echo "$array"
```

First echo prints complete output in one line separated by white space while the other prints outputs in new line. Problem, is, I'm not able to save this output as an array. I tried this:

```
newArray=("$array")
max=${#newArray[@]}
echo $max
```

But echoing 'max' yields '1' on the screen. How can I save the output in an array? I also tried using

```
IFS=\`\n`
```

but could not get the data in an array.

**EDIT**

I used the solution given by Anubhav and it worked like charm. Now I faced a second issue. Since my data contains white spaces, so the array broke at white spaces and wrongly contained the one comments as multiple arrays. So, I used

```
IFS=\`\n`
```

and also used a `$` symbol before backticks. Although this solves my problem, I still get an exception in the logs:

```
test.sh: line 11: n: command not found
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're using backquotes, which is the old-style synonym for `$(...)`. The easiest way to do this is `IFS=$'\n'` (single quotes preceded by a dollar sign).

Comment: @chepner Thanks a ton friend!!!! That indeed worked!!! So many thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put quotes in the command substitution:

```
array=( $(egrep "UserComments/propagateBundle-2013-10-19--04:42:13|UserComments/propagateBundle-2013-10-19--04:38:36|UserComments/propagateBundle-2013-10-19--04:34:24" <path>/propagateBundle.log) )
```

With quotes as in your code whole output is treated as single string in the array.

Comment: Thank you Anubhava for the great response. Please see my Edited post. The second part is causing a problem now.

Answer (score 0):

I've used IFS=('\n') otherwise all "n" chars disappears from results and sort command doesn't work properly. See bellow, it is a customized llq output.

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=('\n')
raw=(`llq -f %id %o %gu %gl %st %BS %c`)
echo
echo ${raw[*]} | grep "step(s)"
echo
echo ${raw[*]} | grep "Step"
echo ${raw[*]} | grep "\---*"
echo ${raw[*]} | grep "bgp-fn*" | sort -k5 -r
echo ${raw[*]} | grep "\---*"
echo ${raw[*]} | grep "Step"
echo
echo ${raw[*]} | grep "step(s)"
echo
```